# Ability to retrieve transcripts from a chat room that was deleted by a moderator?

Tags: support, chat

a couple months ago, a moderator deleted a chat room on StackOverflow and the reason provided was that it was unrelated to the general topic of the website.

The room can be found here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29698/loungetherapy

Since then, I have made several attempts to retrieve the chat transcripts of that room, but have repeatedly failed. It would be very helpful if someone would guide me to those transcripts. A couple of other users and I had some memorable discussions in that room and I would really appreciate if someone would help me get those transcripts back. Please let me know if I need to provide any more information.

Thank You.

**EDIT:** I want to verify that most of the "personal talk" done in that chat room was done by me. I am unsure of the username that I had back then as I changed usernames quite frequently, but in the earlier days of the room, I went by "Demcodelines" and later changed it to "Ash Ketchum." In the later stages, I also went by "TheGuyWhoCouldn'tTalkToTheGirl" but I am unsure if I adopted that name after the chat room was deleted or before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't like this idea very much. Sure, I could post the entire transcript here for you and anyone else to peruse, but...

That chat room was deleted because, as you note, it was very off-topic. A quick glance shows some fairly personal stuff being discussed there. Do you really think *everyone* who was in that room would appreciate it being shared?

Let's move on.

---

Update: in response to requests from several of the folks most active in that room, I've emailed a full transcript to the 7 most active users in that room. Consider this a one-time concession to the room's unfortunate longevity.

Comment: Was this chat room public? If so I guess everyone in that room *would* appreciate it being shared

Comment: The keyword there is *was*.

Comment: Most of the personal things were mine...so it shouldn't be a problem. However, I would appreciate it if you could email it to me instead of posting it here.

Comment: For some reason, I was moderator in this chatroom. I agree with the transcripts being shared. As far as I remember, most of the personal things were actually @AshKetchum ones as stated.

Comment: Yes, I believe *everyone* who was in that room would appreciate it being shared. After all, it was on a public chat site. If we were so inclined, we could have taken our discussion to somewhere a LOT more private.

Comment: @Shog9 is that enough? Can you please pass the transcript now?

Comment: Oh god that room was horrible. I fully support this notion.

Comment: Let's not forget mr. rapey here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9570705#9570705 , Gordon did good judgement when deleting that room.

Answer (score 1):

The transcript is deleted, and as such only 10k users and moderators can view it. All you need to do is get another 9,633 rep to view it.

To be honest though, it is quite obvious why it was deleted from looking at some of the pages in there. I don't think that a chat about relationships is exactly on topic for SO. Perhaps for one of the newer exchanges, such as [Relationships and Dating](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44577/relationships-and-dating).

That being said, if you have something **specific** from that transcript, you should probably point to that instead of asking for the transcript in its entirety (it is kind of long).